# 'SafeAreaView' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Hi I am using react native with typescript for first time. I am getting this error from typescript on all elements from react-native

> TS2786: 'SafeAreaView' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its
> instance type 'SafeAreaView' is not a valid JSX element.     Type
> 'NativeMethods' is missing the following properties from type
> 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 2 more.

I've tried updating @types/react @types/react-dom. I've also tried adding following in package.json and running yarn. but not working for me.

```
 "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that my typescript version was out of date. updating to 5.0.2 solved the issue. Older version was 4.0.8. As it was a major update, I believe the new react-native might be using some syntax or function that was not compatible with TS 4.x